# How to display output in breaklines in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

How if I want to display a set of output in breaklines in HTML? I have separate and join the result using JS, at console it appear as what I want, but not in div tag.

Console Log

[image]

Actual result

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <span id='testing'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var names = 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nameArr = names.replace(/,/g, '\n');
$('#testing').text(nameArr)
```

Comment: in html tag, the breakline is <br>, not \n , you will have to insert <br> after each line of name is inserted.

Comment: span is inline. div is not. as well as <br/> you can swap to div

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.html()` instead of `.text()` and you need to use `<br/>` tag to break the line

```js
var names = 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nameArr = names.replace(/,/g, '<br/>');
$('#testing').html(nameArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <span id='testing'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **CSS**

```
white-space: pre
```

```js
var names = 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nameArr = names.replace(/,/g, '\n');
$('#testing').text(nameArr)
```

```css
#testing {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <span id='testing'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using `<br/>`

```js
var names = 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nameArr = names.replace(/,/g, '<br/>');
$('#testing').html(nameArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <span id='testing'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var names = 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nameArr = names.split(',');
$(nameArr).each(function(index, name) {
  $('#testing').append("<p>" +name+ "</p>")
})
```